# flow type question mark before or after param?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Can someone explain the difference between:

```
function foo(bar: ?string) {
  console.log(bar);
}
```

and:

```
function foo(bar?: string) {
  console.log(bar);
}
```

When to use one over the other?

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/ and https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#optional-parameters-a-classtoc-idtoc-optional-parameters-hreftoc-optional-parametersa

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Basically

```
bar: ?string
```

accepts a string, null or void:

```
foo("test");
foo(null);
foo()
```

While

```
bar?: string
```

Accepts only a string or void:

```
foo("test");
foo();
```

As passing null instead of a string is somewhat senseless, theres no real life difference between them.

Comment: I've seen `bar?: ?string` somewhere, when would you use that? Or does that make no sense?

Comment: @tieme no that makes no sense (at least not to me) :)

Comment: Check. And inside an object literal? `type Styles = { fontName?: ?string; }`

Comment: @tieme doesnt matter.

Comment: It's explained pretty clearly here: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/

Comment: @BradPeabody according to the docs `{ prop?: foo }` is the "optional property syntax" which I'm guessing is a specific usage of the `maybe` syntax

Comment: This is not the correct answer you are looking for; see below for actual correct answer.

Answer (score 13):

`?string` (maybe type) means that `bar` property can be `string` aswell as `null` and `void`.

`bar?` means that this property is optional.

More info: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/