# flow type question mark?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

So confused on using '?' in flow. AFAIK (thanks to [flow type question mark before or after param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314749/flow-type-question-mark-before-or-after-param)):

1. When '?' before ':', means bar is optional, can be string or undefined:

   `bar?: string`
2. When '?' after ':', means bar is maybe type, can be string, undefined, or null.

   `bar: ?string`

My question is: In which circumstance we should the first option over the second? How about `bar?: ?string` ?

flow is hard...

Comment: Please keep in mind that `undefined` does NOT mean `null` and vice versa

Answer (score 7):

Optional means that the property can be omitted. Have a look at this example:

```
type Foo = {
  optional?: string
}

const foo: Foo = {}; // OK

type Bar = {
  maybe: ?string;
}

const bar: Bar = {}; // Error: `maybe` is missing in object literal
```

Regarding combination of optional and maybe - it allows assigning `null` to optional property:

```
type Baz = {
  maybeAndOptional?: ?string;
}

let baz: Baz = {}; // OK
baz = { maybeAndOptional: null }; // OK

type Foo = {
  optional?: string
}

let foo: Foo = {}; // OK
foo = { optional: null } // Error: null is incompatible with string
```

Comment: I see. thanks for clarify:) How about `bar?: ?string` ? I am wondering in which case we should use this?

Comment: @nicemayi Have look at updated answer. But to be fair - I find separation to _optional_ and _maybe_ pretty useless and confusing. I'd prefer to have only optional properties/arguments with ability to assign null values.

Comment: Very clean and concise answer! Thanks Aleksey:)