# What is this question mark prefixing operator?

Tags: typescript, babel-loader

I'm having quite a bit of trouble finding what this operator actually is called, since question marks are used for many things in TypeScript/JavaScript. Anyone have any idea? I can see that it's shorthand for setting `a` to `string | null`, but I don't know what it's actually called and my Babel configuration isn't recognizing it but my ts-loader configuration does.

```js
function test(a: ?string) {
  return undefined
}
```

Comment: It's **not** TypeScript: https://tsplay.dev/Wo559N. Could be [tag:flowtype]: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51182335/3001761.

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-maybe-types

Comment: Well that is fascinating, I'm compiling my types with typescript. How is that possible haha

Comment: I have the same question and cannot find it explained or defined anywhere. At least for me it only works in .d.ts files (type declarations).

Comment: I've did some more experiments and it seems in d.ts files the compiler is more lenient (Try typing your variable as 'xxx').  VSCode seems to mixing it up with Flow definitions.