# What are the two question marks in this code:`options?: ?Object`,The source code of vue.js,at src\core\observer\watcher.js

Tags: vue.js, flowtype

This is the Vue.js source code, I know `OneVar?:string` means optional, but ,What does `oneVar:?string` mean? For Example follwing code at line 16. And I'll get an error if I write `oneVar:?string` in typeScript file

```
export default class Watcher {
  vm: Component;
  expression: string;
  cb: Function;
  id: number;
  deep: boolean;
  user: boolean;
  lazy: boolean;
  sync: boolean;
  dirty: boolean;
  active: boolean;
  deps: Array<Dep>;
  newDeps: Array<Dep>;
  depIds: SimpleSet;
  newDepIds: SimpleSet;
  before: ?Function;
  getter: Function;
  value: any;

  constructor(
    vm: Component,
    expOrFn: string | Function,
    cb: Function,
    options?: ?Object,
    isRenderWatcher?: boolean
  ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is TypeScript? EDIT: it's apparently Flow.

Comment: this questions i get an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314749/flow-type-question-mark-before-or-after-param

Comment: I thought this was TypeScript syntax, but it's actually flow.js syntax. `oneVar:?string` means get a string type or null or void